# subcaption: No space after label (DeclareCaptionFont breaks labelsep)

Tags: spacing, subfloats, subcaption

In the following example I am using `\DeclareCaptionFont` to change the color of the caption labels:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{gray}{\color{gray}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelsep=space, labelfont={sf,gray}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \caption{first subcaption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \caption{second subcaption}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

There is no space after the caption label. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelsep=space,labelfont={gray,sf}}`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Thanks, using `{gray,sf}` instead of `{sf,gray}` fixes the issue.

Comment: It's a bug anyway. I just filled a ticket: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/25/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it's because of the code of captionfont, which will cut off the next space. But you can define an own separator with a prohibited space, which can't be cut off:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{protectedspace}{~}%put in what you like
\DeclareCaptionFont{gray}{\color{gray}}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelsep=protectedspace,labelfont={sf,gray}}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \caption{first subcaption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \caption{second subcaption}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed! if you try to typeset "A B", and then "A\color{gray} B", you'll see that "\color" will gobble the next space. In this case, it would also be possible simply to specify `labelfont={gray,sf}` instead (notice the reversed order).

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, define your entire format to include the changes you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{graysf}{\textcolor{gray}{\sffamily (#2)}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelsep=space,labelformat=graysf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \caption{first subcaption}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \caption{second subcaption}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

From the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf),

> At usage `#1` gets replaced with the name (e.g. “figure”) and `#2` gets replaced with the reference number (e.g. “12”).

As such, I only used `#2` in the definition of the `graysf` caption label format.